# TF-IDF/Cosine Similarity - Similarity Histogram

Tags: machine-learning, unsupervised-learning

I created a [histogram with the similarity scores](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KyjMl.png) of all documents in a corpus. The scores were computed with TF-IDF/Cosine Similarity. See included image. I'm not 100% sure how to read the chart. Does the compactness of scores indicate that the corpus is closely related in a good way or closely related in a bad way? Or am I looking at this completely wrong?

```
tf = TfidfVectorizer(analyzer='word', ngram_range=(1, 2), min_df=5)
tfidf_matrix = tf.fit_transform(ds['clean_text'])
cosine_similarities = linear_kernel(tfidf_matrix, tfidf_matrix)
```

Comment: 1) there is no image link.
2) What are you trying to learn/assess from the plot?

Comment: I guess I needed the description for the link to show.  I'm trying to learn generally how accurate the results are in relation to the corpus.  I'm assuming since similarity score peak around 0.6 and compacted well that the results are fairly decent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the histogram, It would seem that the document similarity is not that concentrated (Cosine simlarity is bounded [0,1], and your histogram range is ~0.2-1). Whether this is good or bad depends on your expectation of the data, and what you want to do with the TF-IDF matrix later on. If you have a diverse corpus (e.g. wikipedia) then you would expect a wide range and be suspicious if you had a narrow range of Cosine similarity scores. However, if your Corpus is derived from a highly similar set of documents (e.g. a book report from a class of students).

In general, the distribution of your similarity scores is more just an FYI than a measure of dataset quality.

Comment: The corpus is (diverse) press release data so the .2 to 1 range is about what I expected.  The histogram peaks in the .6 to .7 range which I thought was promising and the sample testing I did looks good for a general recommendation engine. Any other advise you can provide when looking at the histogram?